# Getting result from activities in succession

Tags: android, android-fragments, startactivityforresult

**Situation:**

I have three activities situated like so

Activity A/Fragment A --> Activity B/Fragment B --> Activity C/Fragment C

My ultimate goal is to retrieve the result from C back to A. I have done so using startactivityforresult().

**Problem:**

When in activity C, I press either the navigation up or back button and then re-enter activity C from B. Afterwards, I finish with the activity and press ok. I set the result and finish. Activity B retrieves the result in onActivityResult and everything is fine (request code is good with 0 and resultcode equals RESULT_OK). Activity B then sets this same result and finishes. However, when onActivityResult is called in Activity A, why is it that the result code 0 and the data is null?

I thought startactivityforresult only sends back the result to the previous direct activity.

**Activity A**

```
FloatingActionButton fab = (FloatingActionButton) findViewById(R.id.activity_search_fab);
    fab.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            startActivityForResult(new Intent(v.getContext(), SearchActivity.class), REQUEST_RESTAURANT);
        }
    });
```

**Activity B**

```
@Override
public void onClick(View v) {
    Intent intent = new Intent(v.getContext(), AddActivity.class);
    intent.putExtra(EXTRA_YELP_RESTAURANT, mRestaurant);
    ((Activity)v.getContext()).startActivityForResult(intent, FavoritesActivity.REQUEST_RESTAURANT);
}

@Override
public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    if ((requestCode == FavoritesActivity.REQUEST_RESTAURANT) &&
            (resultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK)) {
        setResult(resultCode, data);
        finish();
    }
}
```

**Activity C**

```
@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    switch (item.getItemId()) {
        case R.id.add_done_check:
            Intent data = new Intent();
            data.putExtra(EXTRA_MY_RESTAURANT, mRestaurant);
            getActivity().setResult(Activity.RESULT_OK, data);
            getActivity().finish();
            break;
        default:
            return false;
    }
    return true;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem seemed to be that when the navigation up button was pressed, a new intent was created for Activity B. This somehow removed the startactivityforresult() relationship between Activity A and Activity B (How this relationship works I'm not too clear). The solution was to just reuse the previous Activity B instead of creating another one by doing:

```
android:launchmode="singleTop"
```

inside the manifest file for Activity B

Comment: I don't think that is the reason. I just wrote a demo and everything worked as expected.

Comment: Does your Activity A handles onActivityResult() correctly?